# How to run a report to identify out of hours cases

Tags: reporting, case, time

I am trying to run a report detailing the cases which are received out of hours and have a chart associated.

I found the below on a site

```
IF(
LEN( CREATED_DATE ) = 1,
          '0' + CREATED_DATE + ':00 - 0' + CREATED_DATE + ':59',
          CREATED_DATE + ':00 - ' + CREATED_DATE + ':59'
  )
```

but when I try to run it I get the below error.

Warning
Error when encoding row-level formula: Incorrect parameter type for function 'LEN()'. Expected Text, received DateTime

has anyone got any ideas on how to fix this or a formula that would work?

Comment: `CREATED_DATE` (from the formula) and `CreatedDate`  (what I imagine you're using instead) are likely different, meaning this formula/approach is probably not suited to your situation. Which site did you find this on? That'd probably help determine which circumstances this is meant to work with.

Comment: Also, the more details you can include, the better. What constitutes "out of hours" for you? Do you have people in multiple time zones that would use this report (which would definitely complicate matters)? Can you use flows and/or apex/triggers in your org? Please [edit] your question to add those details.